# Installing SSL cert in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-swarm

I am using `docker stack`  to deploy one service in multiple digital ocean droplets (replica > 1), one container per droplet. This is my app backend service.

I want to have a SSL cert & private key installed (and hopefully automatically renewed) so I can use TLS connection, with SSL termination setting, so data transfer from swarm LB to containers is unencrypted using port 80. I also use `docker-machine` cmd to setup my digital ocean ubuntu v16.04 droplet.

**What is the best way of doing this?**

I tried the following, and two issues arised:

1. I am first generating the cert and private key with let's encrypt somewhere else on a server with nginx installed (messing with my DNS also). After the cert/key generation, I then copy and install them back with `docker swarm ca --rotate`. But feel this approach is wrong.
2. With 1.  set, I tried `curl` the backend service. The port 80 is fine, but port 443 seems to be talking http protocol, and I see the following:

   ```
   $ curl -vvv https://myurl.com:443/v1/check 
   *   Trying my.ip.address... 
   * Connected to myurl.com (my.ip.address) port 443 (#0) 
   * found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt 
   * found 593 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
   * ALPN, offering http/1.1
   * gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
   * Closing connection 0

   curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.

   $ curl -vvv http://myurl.com:443/v1/check
   *   Trying my.ip.address...
   * Connected to myurl.com (my.ip.address) port 443 (#0)
   > GET /v1/check HTTP/1.1
   > Host: myurl.com:443
   > User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
   > Accept: */*
   >
   < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   < Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
   < Date: Sun, 09 Sep 2018 11:06:39 GMT
   < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
   < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   < Connection: keep-alive
   < Vary: Accept-Encoding, Origin
   < ETag: W/"843adc298b0b2ef417eabf2f82670fc9"
   < Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
   < X-Request-Id: b201d205-4c63-4318-b965-cebabc056b29
   < X-Runtime: 0.078911
   < X-Rack-Cache: pass
   <
   * Connection #0 to host myurl.com left intact
   {"status":"ok","container_id":"8bd9981213e7"}
   ```

Thank you for shedding light on this subject!

I have also asked the question here:

https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-ssl-cert-in-docker-swarm/58073

Answer (score 2):

You can generate certificates manually using the OpenSSL tool and configure Docker daemon to use these certificates.

**Generate Server Certificates**

1. Generate CA private and public keys:

   ```
   openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca-key.pem 4096
   openssl req -new -x509 -days 1000 -key ca-key.pem -sha256 -out ca.pem
   ```
2. Create a server key and certificate signing request (CSR):

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 4096
   openssl req -subj "/CN=my.company.com" -sha256 -new -key server-key.pem -out server.csr
   ```
3. Sign the public key with CA:

   ```
   echo subjectAltName = DNS:my.company.com,IP:127.0.0.1 >> extfile.cnf
   echo extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth >> extfile.cnf
   ```
4. Generate the key:

   ```
   openssl x509 -req -days 1000 -sha256 -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf
   ```

**Generate Client Certificates**

1. Create a client key and certificate signing request:

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out key.pem 4096
   openssl req -subj '/CN=client' -new -key key.pem -out client.csr
   ```
2. Create an extensions config file:

   ```
   echo extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth >> extfile.cnf
   ```
3. Sign the private key:

   ```
   openssl x509 -req -days 1000 -sha256 -in client.csr -CA ../server/ca.pem -CAkey ../server/ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf
   ```
4. Export cert.pem into PFX format to be added into Trusted Root Certification Authorities

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out cert.pfx
   ```

**Configure Docker daemon with /etc/docker/daemon.json**

```
{
    "debug": false,
    "tls": true,
    "tlsverify": true,
    "tlscacert": "/etc/docker/certificates/server/ca.pem",
    "tlscert": "/etc/docker/certificates/server/server-cert.pem",
    "tlskey": "/etc/docker/certificates/server/server-key.pem",
    "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2376", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
}
```

**Start Docker Service**

```
systemctl start docker
```

Check out this article [Building Jenkins Pipelines – Part 1. Setting Up Docker Swarm](https://scalified.com/2018/10/08/building-jenkins-pipelines-docker-swarm/) by Scalified.

It includes a step-by-step guide on how to setup Docker Swarm and generate server and client self-signed certificates. I hope it will help to solve your issue.